# Android Login button stops working

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Hi I am developing an android app, but my `login button` not working properly, as I am able to signup with `web service` but after in login page its stopped working, as I can navigate from signup to other page but login button does not let me login, please help me, below is my code for login functionality

thanks

```
public class Login extends ActionBarActivity {
Button btnLogin;
Button fbbutton;
Button gpbutton;
Button twbutton;
Button btnRegister;

EditText username, password;
String uname, pass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    Button btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    //import button
    Button btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Signup.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });


}

public void send(View v) {
    try {

        // CALL post method to make post method call
        post();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        String error = ex.getMessage();
    }

}

//Method to get list value pair and form the query
private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for (NameValuePair pair : params) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}


//Method to post data to webservice
public void post() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    try {
        // Calling async task to get json
        new DownloadOperation().execute();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//Handle popout messages
public void error(boolean flag, String etext) {
    if (flag == true) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), etext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Code to handle failure
        username.setText("");
        password.setText("");

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), etext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

    }
}

private class DownloadOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    String uname = "";
    String pass = "";


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Get user defined values
        uname = username.getText().toString();
        pass = password.getText().toString();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String response = "";
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://rgbpallete.in/led/api/login");
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", uname));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", pass));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            return response;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonStr) {
        super.onPostExecute(jsonStr);
        Log.d("tag", "Result:\n" + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                String message = jsonObj.getString("message");
                boolean error = jsonObj.getBoolean("error");

                error(error, message);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

layout code of `btnLogin` Button

```
<Button 
   android:id="@+id/btnLogin" 
   style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button.Borderless"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_below="@+id/password" 
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
   android:layout_marginTop="20dp" 
   android:background="@drawable/button" 
   android:text="Login" 
   android:textColor="#ffffff" 
   android:textSize="20sp" 
   android:onClick="welcome" />
```

Comment: Please show code of login button's onclick and crash time logcat,

Comment: Actually i am not getting any error while rnuning the app, and also  my emulator not working so everytime i had to check that in my cell

Comment: **but my login button not working properly**. Show its code.

Comment: Please wait a second pasting log cat error

Comment: you mean to xml file

Comment: Have you added onClick attribute in xml for button? then yes, show it.

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:onClick="welcome" />

Answer (score 2):

change this line to

```
Button btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
```

to this

```
btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
```

you are not initialize it properly.you are creating new variable.if you are getting null pointer exception that would be the reason

Comment: but he neithor set any `onClickListener` for that Button `btnLogin` nor has a method `welcome` in Activity

Answer (score 2):

Your application is crashing because in xml you have set `onClick` as `welcome`(as per your comment). But you haven't implement it in `Activity`. So, when you click on that Button you are getting `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`. In `Activity` `welcome` method is required add this in `Activity`

```
public void welcome(View v) {
   //do your action i.e call AsyncTask
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you have registered onclick listener to your login button, you haven't registered any click listener with **btnLogin** and also not set any action to be performed onClick to btnLogin!! just implemented those in btnRegister! I think you forgot it!!
2. if you are using onclick attribute of xml; then make sure these things are correct regarding your method:

a. your method is public and is the member of the Activity.

b. corresponding method should have one parameter, whose type should match the XML object. eg: View

Comment: 12-24 14:29:26.199  21349-21349/com.example.abhi.micro D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
12-24 14:29:26.569  21349-21349/com.example.abhi.micro I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method

Comment: if not getting proper reply to my questions , how can i help u? now the problem seems to be with your xml which you are inflating

Comment: here is welcome method
public class Welcome extends ActionBarActivity {

    @****Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
    }


    @****Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

Comment: i want to do basically when user login it will redirect to welcome layout page

Comment: may i ask yoou one thing, is that your welcome method? isn't a class??? and if you were giving the code with the question or when we asked for it, you could save time

Comment: sorry buddy i am just beginner but trying to learn, i apologize and also thanking you.

Comment: can you tell me code for throwing unsupported java.io exception

Comment: add the line "throws IOException" to the begining of the block you want to throw exception. also you can use try-catch for the same

Comment: Hi i am using Android studio

Comment: have you done as i said above? i mean adding the throws cluase at the beginning of the block/

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67608/discussion-on-answer-by-bachu-android-login-button-stops-working).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing

Button  btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

```
    btnLogin .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            //all your stuff here
        }
    });
```

Add and test.. Actually for each `button` you have to use `OnClickListener`